# What is the difference between lineHeight and leading?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, fonts, uitextview, uifont

I understand that, in ye olden days of typesetting, 'leading' was the total height of the lead blocks used for the letters - i.e. the height of the lines.

So, in my UITextView, what is the difference between `textView.font.leading` and `textView.font.lineHeight`? Both return the same values in NSLogs in the fonts I've tried.

(Extra info - I need this because I'm programatically creating a 'lined notepaper' effect, and I need the line height to change depending on the font size).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Deprecated in iOS 4.0
>   leading The receiver’s leading
>   information. (read-only) (Deprecated
>   in iOS 4.0. Use the lineHeight
>   property instead.)
>
> @property(nonatomic, readonly) CGFloat
>   leading Discussion The leading value
>   represents the spacing between lines
>   of text and is measured (in points)
>   from baseline to baseline.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 2.0 and
>   later. Deprecated in iOS 4.0. Declared
>   In UIFont.h

[Deprecated UIFont Methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIFont/leading)

Comment: So it is the same thing then - I take it they just renamed it to make it clearer. Odd - XCode 4 normally warns me when things are deprecated.

Comment: `lineHeight` was added in 4.0, and is marked as such in the header with `NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_0)`, but for some reason `leading` is not marked. It should be something like `NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0,4_0)`.